# Golang getting the result of a reflection call

Tags: go, reflection

I'm making a reflection function call but I'm currently stuck on trying to get the return values.

Example code:

```
func (c *Client) Send(funcName protoFunction, data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    funcList := c.GetProtoFuncList()
    ctx := context.Background()
    f := reflect.ValueOf(funcList[funcName.String()])
    vals := make([]reflect.Value, 2)
    vals[0] = reflect.ValueOf(ctx)
    vals[1] = reflect.ValueOf(data)
    value := f.Call(vals)
    log.Debug(value)
    return nil, nil
}
```

How do I get the return values from "value" and return them correctly?

Cheers

Comment: You're getting them. `value` in your code will be a slice of the returned values. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: If you look at the [`Call` signature](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call), your `value` is a `[]reflect.Value`. You even print this out. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you use reflection, why don't you just call it directly, and return the results, e.g. `return funcList[funcName.String()].(func(context.Context, interface{})) (interface{}, error)) (ctx, data)`? (The type assertion is only needed if different types of functions are stored in `funcList`; if not, you can even get rid of that and it becomes `return funcList[funcName.String()](ctx, data)`.)

Comment: The return type is of type Value however I would to return the called values with the send() function as type interface{}, error. How do I type cast the error in []Value to be of type error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Value.Call()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call) returns the return values of the function call as a `[]reflect.Value`. You may use the [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) method to get the value represented by a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) as an `interface{}` value. From there, you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain values of different types.

Like in this simplified example:

```
var funcList = map[string]interface{}{
    "test": func(ctx context.Context, data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        return "test-result-data:" + fmt.Sprint(data), errors.New("test-error")
    },
}

func Send(funcName string, data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    f := reflect.ValueOf(funcList[funcName])
    params := []reflect.Value{
        reflect.ValueOf(context.Background()),
        reflect.ValueOf(data),
    }
    res := f.Call(params)

    ret := res[0].Interface()
    var err error
    if v := res[1].Interface(); v != nil {
        err = v.(error)
    }
    return ret, err
}
```

Testing it:

```
result, err := Send("test", "testData")
fmt.Println(result, err)
```

Output:

```
test-result-data:testData test-error
```

But this is unnecessarily complex. You don't need to use reflection to call a function, you may call it directly and return the results directly, like this:

```
func Send2(funcName string, data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    return funcList[funcName].(func(context.Context, interface{}) (interface{}, error))(
        context.Background(), data,
    )
}
```

Testing it:

```
result, err = Send2("test", "testData")
fmt.Println(result, err)
```

Output is the same. Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VCsmK43Zwv).

Comment: Thank you for that clear response. This was exactly what I needed.